# RTCMultiConnection get back to current stream

Tags: javascript, stream, webrtc

Im using RTCMultiConnection v3 plugin i can't figure it out how to get current stream reopened.

Scenario;

UserA opens cam, appends the stream automaticly to `$("#webcam")`. Stream is open.

UserA wants to join UserB and does `connection.join("UserB")` (pretending UserB has also a cam stream). Now this `html()` to `$("#webcam")` so UserA ``$("#webcam")` is overrided by UserB stream but UserA stream is a live. So far so good.

Now i want to reappend UserA stream as UserA does `connection.join("UserA")` his own stream.

I hope someone knows how to do this ? 
I don't want to reopen the whole stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The person who opens a room, must NOT join same room.

You can access the videos (media-streams) using following methods:

#### 1) if you know the "video-id" commonly named as "stream-id"

```
var streamEvent = connection.streamEvents['stream-id'];
var mediaStreamObject = streamEvent.stream;
var videoFreshURL = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStreamObject);
yourVideo.src = videoFreshURL;
```

#### 2) if you know th remote user's Unique-ID commonly named as "userid"

```
var userPeer = connection.peers['user-id'].peer;
var allIncomingVideos = userPeer.getRemoteStreams();
var firstIncomingVideo = allIncomingVideos[0];
var firstVideoFreshURL = URL.createObjectURL(firstIncomingVideo);
yourVideo.src = firstVideoFreshURL;
```

#### 3) store event video in your own object

```
window.yourOwnGlobalObject = {};
connection.onstream = function(event) {
   window.yourOwnGlobalObject[event.userid] = event;
   document.body.appendChild( event.mediaElement );
};

function getUserXYZVideo(userid) {
    var userVideo = window.yourOwnGlobalObject[userid].mediaElement;
    // var userStream = window.yourOwnGlobalObject[userid].stream;
    return userVideo;
}
```